# How to correctly make a PDO statement with PHP variables as parameters?

Tags: php, mysql, parameters, pdo

I currently have the following code:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DATABASE_HOST.';dbname='.DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mdr_contacts SET fkRelatieId = 0, reseller = 0, code = :code, naam = :naam");
$dbh->execute(array(":code" => $contact["contact_id"],":naam" => $name));
```

However this seems to fail: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in file.php on line 67`

What i've done so far to make this work:

1. Checked if `$name` and `$contact` exists and has the right value.
2. Executed a SELECT query before the prepare statement to make sure that PDO works.
3. Runned the code without ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES set to false.

But none of this works, can anyone set me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You execute a statement, not a connection.  `prepare()` on a connection, returns a statement.

Also, I prefer to explicitly call bind on values, but this is just my OCD prefs.

```
 $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mdr_contacts SET fkRelatieId = 0, reseller = 0, code = :code, naam = :naam");
 $statement->bindValue(":code", $contact["contact_id"]);
 $statement->bindValue(":naam", $name);
 $statement->execute();
```

Comment: my god i feel like such an idiot. This completly works. Thanks.

Comment: @RTB  no problem... also check your spelling of 'name' ;)